# Best practice to count rows to prove feedback before processing them

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11g

I'm looking for the best way to count the number of rows I'm going to use for some calculus before actually using them. The reason is that I need to prove feedback like "analyzed 1/100 rows", "analyzed 2/100 rows" and so on.

I'm talking about like 7000 rows and a time of execution of the count distinct of 2 mins.

The worst thing is that, for now I have to using a query to get the count, and then open a cursor that is totally the same of the previous one (except for the count) and start analyze, so the code is duplicated and each time I need to modify the where clause I have to do it twice.

I thought of putting my cursor as a local variable then run in pl/sql a while loop to increase a counter, but I'm not sure about the performance so that is the reason why I'm asking you some advice.

Really hope the answers will not be to use some magic properties of an opened cursor that contains the total row numbers because I would feel very stupid :(

Unless of proven performance gain i prefer to not use a count(*) over (partition by) because i consider it too difficoult to understand at first sight.

Thanks to all

Comment: I would select in temp table IDs of all the rows you need. Then you can count them and use for other calculations.

Comment: It sounds like you are processing the rows one at a time in a loop anyway, so I'm not sure what overhead you are concerned about with the PL/SQL loop approach. An analytic `count` is the way to do this, not sure what's hard about it or why that matters. Or populate a temp table or a collection (for small volumes as this is shared server memory). I'm not sure what kind of answer would help though.

Comment: The fact is that i would like to put in the loop only the code that really needs to all the iterations.  Using the `count(*) over()` i have to insert an `if iteration=0 then write "there are **n** records to evaluate"`, in my env this simple row means 10 rows of code (don't think I need to explain why). For now i assume that the best practice is to use the `count`

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Add a tag for the version. If using Oracle 12.1 or later, you can improve the performance of the `count(*)` by `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(manager_id)` if an exact count is not necessary; and in this case seems like "There are approximately x rows" this function would do nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COUNT(*) OVER()`:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR my_cur IS
  SELECT t.c, COUNT(*) OVER() AS total FROM tab t;

  v_c INT;
  v_total_rows INT;
  v_i INT :=0;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cur;

  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN my_cur%NOTFOUND;
    FETCH my_cur INTO v_c, v_total_rows;

    IF v_i = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Total number of rows to process: ' || v_total_rows);
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Current value :' || v_c);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Progress: ' || 100.0 * v_i / v_total_rows || '%');
    v_i := v_i + 1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE my_cur;
END;
//
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02e7c325508914be225fd1ab59ea764a)**

---

Instead of printing to `DBMS_OUTPUT` you could use [SET_SESSION_LONGOPS](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dbms_application_info#set_session_longops)

Comment: Yes, but if possible i'd prefer to not use analytic functions, anyway you think this query have good performance?

Comment: @VincenzoRaimondi Never ever take anything as granted. This is very simple toy scenario. You should measure and check solution on your env.

Comment: Yes i did it, the query works well, the only problem is that i must write a top line like "there are v_total_rows rows ready". This mean that i have to insert a  `if v_i = 0 then put_line(v_total_rows) end if;` IN the loop..i'd prefer to avoid this because i thinks it compromise legibility of the code..maybe i'm wrong

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT won't show up until the PL/SQL block completes, so using dbms_application_info.set_session_longops that can be monitored by a separate process would be the better way.

Comment: @MarkStewart having to log also other information, in addition to the dbms_application_info.set_session_longops of which I will certainly consider , for the moment the log is inserted in a dedicated table with autonomous transaction

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the full number of rows of a table, you can use the data dictionary's `num_rows` (provided the statistics is up to date):

```
CREATE TABLE mytest AS SELECT * FROM all_objects;

BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MYTEST'); END;
/

SELECT num_rows FROM user_tables WHERE table_name='MYTEST';
-- 60715
```

If your query is more complicated and filters out rows or does other fancy things, and if an estimate of the expected number of rows is good enough, you could use Oracle's built in query planner. It needs to figure out how many rows are to be expected to find the optimal way of querying it:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'st1-seq' FOR 
  SELECT * FROM mytest WHERE object_type = 'SEQUENCE';
SELECT cardinality from plan_table WHERE statement_id='st1-seq' and operation='SELECT STATEMENT';
10

EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'st1-java' FOR 
  SELECT * FROM mytest WHERE object_type = 'JAVA CLASS';
SELECT cardinality from plan_table WHERE statement_id='st1-java' and operation='SELECT STATEMENT';
37563
```